# Apply function to select specific words from each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

Could you please give me a hint how to make this work?

I have made a function which should pick specific words from each row depending on the first element of the sentence of each row of a dataframe:

```
 def distilerator(string):
  '''Input: a dataframe row containing a sentence
     Output: depending on the first word, return a specific selection'''
    if string.str.contains("hello"):
      return string.str.split('\\n')[0]
    else:
      return string.str.split('\\n')[0:2]
```

The dataframe is:

```
A             B
hello\blah    456
123\foo\bar   678
```

And the apply function I try to "apply" to a new column called "description":

```
df['description'] = df['A'].apply(distilerator, axis=1) #axis =1 aims to apply to each row
```

The required product is a dataframe like this:

```
A             B       description
hello\blah    456     hello
123\foo\bar   678     foo bar
```

I tried to express myself as best as I could...

Comment: You are applying the function to series, remove the `.str` accessor insidie your function (think why?).

Comment: Then I can't use contain and if I use <code>'hello' in string<code> I get <code>argument of type 'float' is not iterable<code>

Comment: `df['A'].fillna('').apply(...)`?

Comment: Hmm it creates the required column but it returns a copy of column A. You are in the right way though!